# Pdf of the product of an exponential rv and a $f_Y=Ka^{-K}y^{K-1}$ distributed rv ...

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ are 2 independent random variables, where $X$ has an exponential distribution with parameter $1$ and $Y$ has the following Pdf: $f_Y=Ka^{-K}y^{K-1}, 0 \le y \le a $.

Someone claims that the product $Z=XY$ is $\Gamma(K,a)$ distributed. Is it true ? if yes, how to prove it ? if not, then what is the distribution of $Z$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: Who is someone?

Comment: I don't know his name. is it really necessary ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X \sim Exponential(1)$ with pdf $f_x(x)$ and $Y \sim PowerFunction(a,k)$ with pdf $f_y(y)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/ExponentialandPowerFunctionpdf.png))</sub>

Then the pdf of $Z = X Y$ is:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/productofExponentialPowerFunction.png))</sub>

where:

1. The `TransformProduct` function is from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*. As disclosure, I should add that I am one of the authors.
2. `ExpIntegralE[n,z]` denotes the exponential integral function $E_n(z)=\int _{1}^{\infty }\frac{e^{-z t}}{t^n} dt$
3. Your friend 'someone' is incorrect:  the pdf is not a Gamma random variable.

Comment: Thank you @wolfies ! Now I'am looking for the Pdf of $Z$ multiplied by $W$, where $W$ is $\beta(b,c)$ distributed. Any idea ?